# How do I fix the Helix Swarm config so it pings the correct hostname

Tags: version-control, perforce, swarm

I have gotten Helix Core and Helix Swarm installed as a server extension on my server. When I initially configured it I set the hostname to `swarmhostname` because I didn't have a DNS record set up.

Once I had the DNS record `swarm.mydomain.com` record set up I:

1. edited the hostname in `/opt/perforce/swarm/data/config.ini` to `swarm.mydomain.com`
2. checked that P4.Swarm.URL is correct
3. rebooted the apache server (and p4dctl just to be safe)
4. successfully connected to swarm website with `swarm.mydomain.com`

However, I can't actually commit anything to my depot as it says hostname failed to resolve.
When I run `p4 extension --run swarm ping` I get `cannot reach http://swarmhostname/`

I've tried clicking the refresh configuration button on the swarm site and it correctly shows the hostname as `swarm.mydomain.com`. Why is p4 still trying to access it as if it's in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you also update the Swarm extension's config?

Run:

```
p4 extension --configure Perforce::helix-swarm
```

Check the value for Swarm-URL.

Your "ping" test output says it is "http://swarmhostname/".

Adjust it to match your new swarm.mydomain.com

The change is immediate - no restart(s) needed.

Comment: This is it. I didn't run this step during the initial install because I installed from the package. This step is in the tarball installation for anyone else looking in the future.